# Anylogic Model : Resource charts

Tags: anylogic

I have developed a model with some resource pools: Workers namely – Warehouse workers, production workers and outbound workers; and also Transporters namely – Fork lifters in Inbound, Warehouse and Staging areas. To plot a resource utilization for the model, I included two plotting charts separately – one for workers and one for transporters as shown in the pic. So when the model is simulated, the charts starts plotting. But I get only the results for the area of warehouse. For the rest of the areas – Inbound, Staging and Outbound, I don’t get any plotting. It is just blank line along 0 on y-axis. I have attached some pics of the properties. Please let me know how can I change it?

[Workers Resource utilization properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ2up.png)

[Fork lifters Utilization properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaPnF.png)

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B29P3.png)

This is my Thesis. so I would like to know how to retrieve the utilization information from the model so i can justify the model with its purpose.

Comment: Are you sure it is the charts that are wrong? Or is the model actually not working and the charts just show you that there is nothing happening?

Comment: Strange to hear that it doesn't work. You could try to replace the values in the visualization with *name of resourcePool* followed by ".utilization()". This method will return the utilization (data type double) as the model runs.